# Boost Up hashing speed with cost 20 or more

Tags: php, execution, password-hash, php-password-hash

I'm using

```
password_hash(myPassword,PASSWORD_DEFAULT,['cost'=>20])
```

in PHP.
But it fails to execute the hashed password

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

I use a computer with below hardware:
16GB RAM
8GB Graphic Card
CPU Core i7-8700K 3.70GHz

How can I execute large costs in shorter time???
What do I need to use to power up my computer to achieve a good result in shorter time???

Comment: What happens when you try it without the 2nd & 3rd arguments? `password_hash(myPassword)` ?

Comment: The [`password_hash` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) provide a sample script for calculating a reasonable cost value for your server (example #4). You shouldn't just be picking one arbitrarily.

Comment: This takes 1.2 minutes on my i5-6500. `password_hash()` is a single-threaded operation so if you overclock your CPU or buy a CPU with a higher IPC then you should be able to achieve better times.

Comment: Increasing the cost factor by 1 means doubling the time to hash a password. Nowadays a reasonable factor is 10 so your factor needs about 1000 times longer.

Answer (score 3):

The point of a large cost is exactly that it requires more computing power. To hash a large cost faster, execute it on a faster machine. To make hashing usable on the machine you have, choose a cost that results in a reasonable (read: as slow as possible, as fast as necessary) hash time.

The goal is to make it usable for a one-time hash to store/check the password, but entirely infeasible for someone to try to brute-force a hash by trying it many many times.

`20` is ludicrous and unusable in practice to date.

Comment: Never realized cost was exponential.  The difference between 12 and 20 is huge.